# ARC working method and Necessity of Strong, Weak and UnOwned references

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, swift2, automatic-ref-counting

I was facing problem with deallocation of View Controller in my code, then I read about how ARC work and about Strong, Weak and UnOwned references. I was wondering, why swift has made it so complicated? deallocation problem could be solved using slightly different method than what ARC method does. Here is my method:

We can think dependency between objects as directed graph, and can find an unReachable part of graph from current location using proper(using flags) BFS search(in O(n)), and then we can de-initialise all instances which are in unreachable part of graph. Then we can directly work with strong references and there will be no need for weak or unowned references.

Am I missing something here? May be some performance issue or some limitations. Can someone please give me a reason for necessity of Strong, Weak and UnOwned references or some article/document which can explain reason for above in detail?

Comment: do you have any protocols using in your viewController?

Comment: Yup.. I can solve it using weak and unowned references, but question is different, Why are you asking this??

Answer (score 0):

This is the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) and this is a [more entertaining discussion](https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift). For the most part ARC stays out of your way, just requiring some hints e.g. when creating closures that reference self but execute in the context of another component.

Comment: I have actually kind of gone through these documents.. they are only telling how to use these (strong, weak and unowed) but not why they are handling it on ARC level itself using BFS or some other algo as I asked in question. If I have missed something then please tell me exact line number or something in above posts where I can find exact answer of my question.. thanks.. :)